# Python: ModuleNotFoundError and cross-computer compatibility of 'import' (i.e. for homework submissions)

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to submit a script where I tabulate a datalist.

So I go:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
datalist = [...]
...
print(tabulate(datalist, headers = [..., ..., ...]))
```

Now on my laptop, I can `pip install tabulate` through Powershell admin (but not through Python directly, which is another question I have: why?). This allows `tabulate` to be imported from my script because I guess it's in the path now.

My question is: how do I account for my TA's or prof's computer? They probably won't take the extra step to `pip install tabulate`.

I am supposed to submit a .zip file so I was thinking maybe I could download some file into my project folder. So I searched for the `tabulate` documentation and I saw downloadable files (.whl and .tar.gz) but I don't really know what to do with them.

So TLDR:
I wanna learn how to:

- make the `import` function work in my script (straight from the script) no matter which computer it is ran in, and
- use .whl or .tar.gz files to add to my project folder so that no matter what, `import` still works.

Comment: "but not through Python directly, which is another question I have: why?": because Python is the interpreter for a programming language, not a package manager. Arguably, things are related, but for most programming languages, this is the case: separate interpreters/compilers and package managers. Also, if you really wanted to, you could `import pip` and have all the power of pip inside Python. But I'd advise against that, since you'll find little to no documentation or help doing it that way.

Comment: "They probably won't take the extra step to pip install tabulate.": You say "probably": have you asked them? Are external packages allowed? If they are, they should take the extra steps to install the package(s), and you should mention that in the requirements. If external packages are not allowed, then don't use `tabulate`.